# Display name is incorrect in people picker

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, display-name

One of the Users 'Last Name' and 'Email Address' are changed and updated in the Active Directory. The updated name can also be seen in 'Manage User Properties' link in the Central Admin.

But when I tried to check permissions for the user using 'Check Permissions' link in Site Permissions, I still see the old name. I did a Incremental Profile sync. Also, Important point to note is that this name change happened in Nov,2015 and still the SharePoint People Picker control shows Old name.

Comment: Do you use mySites on that farm? I had once similar case on farm without and the mySiteCleanUp job resolved it (in my case it wasn't running)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes we have mySites but then on the users mysite I can see the updated name. This happens only on the people picker.

Comment: I fix this by deleting the user from the site collection hidden users list: http://blog.incworx.com/blog/consulting-from-the-trenches/remove-user-from-sharepoint-2013-site-collection-user-list

Comment: You shouldn't delete them. You have now orphaned any reference to their work. The user Id will change in that site collection. All you need to do is have them work in the site and make an Edit or an Addition. The User Profile will sync their UIL record with their User Profile.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the particular database is not updating correctly. Run the following:

```
stsadm -o sync -listolddatabases 0
```

Are any databases >0 days? If so, run:

```
stsadm -o sync -deleteolddatabases 0
```

The next time the UPSA -> UIL synchronization job runs, the display name should be updated.